# Extract values from after "&": value="&videoId=139209&videoUrl=https://mp5.website.net

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have these different links that all contain different content, where I am trying to get the data from.

I succeed to some point but now I am stuck and looking for help to understand Beautiful Soup better.

The documentation haven't helped me much in this particular matter and no google searches has been able to help me.

My script is like this:

```
r = requests.get(link)
raw = r.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(raw, features="html.parser")

inputTag = soup.find("input", {"id": "videoId"})
output = inputTag["value", "videoUrl"]

print(output)
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how to get specific input values (after each "&") in a long string  like:

```
<input type="text" style="display: none" id="videoId" value="&videoId=139209&videoUrl=https://mp5.website.net/storage1/M03/10/92/aPODC10sfP-AcFDnAGhUgdKc7iA667.mp4&videoImg=https://mp5.website.net/storage1/M03/10/97/aPODCl0sfP-ACNFjAABmn9NL64Q064.png&videoIntroduction=[{"content":"Everything in the world is a matrix","type":1,"userId":""}]userNickName=Califax'>
```

If I leave my `output = inputTag["value"]` like this, I get the 'value', but how I parse for example videoId= and videoUrl= has got me confused.

Hope someone can guide me in the right direction to how I achieve this.

---

Edit for the JSON part.

With your suggest code I get this error now:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/run/media/anonymous/06bcf743-8b4d-409f-addc-520fc4e19299/PycharmProjects/learningcurve/video_moments.py", line 34, in <module>
    videoIntroduction = json.loads(output['videoIntroduction'][0])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 85 (char 84)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `urllib` (Fixed formatting noted by @facelessuser

```
import urllib.parse
import json

value = '&videoId=139209&videoUrl=https://mp5.website.net/storage1/M03/10/92/aPODC10sfP-AcFDnAGhUgdKc7iA667.mp4&videoImg=https://mp5.website.net/storage1/M03/10/97/aPODCl0sfP-ACNFjAABmn9NL64Q064.png&videoIntroduction=[{"content":"Everything in the world is a matrix","type":1,"userId":""}]userNickName=Califax'
```

Because this is malformed, some basic fixes can be made. Something like:

```
fixed_value = value.replace(']user', ']&user')

output = urllib.parse.parse_qs(fixed_value)
```

which
yields
a
dictionary

```
{'videoId': ['139209'], 'videoUrl': ['https://mp5.website.net/storage1/M03/10/92/aPODC10sfP-AcFDnAGhUgdKc7iA667.mp4'], 'videoImg': ['https://mp5.website.net/storage1/M03/10/97/aPODCl0sfP-ACNFjAABmn9NL64Q064.png'], 'videoIntroduction': ['[{"content":"Everything in the world is a matrix","type":1,"userId":""}]'], 'userNickName': ['Califax']}
```

so
for your case something like

```
output = urllib.parse.parse_qs(inputTag["value"])
```

You can access the elements as dictionaries and list indexing

```
print(output['videoIntroduction'][0])
[{"content":"Everything in the world is a matrix","type":1,"userId":""}]userNickName=Califax
```

which is a JSON string, so decode it into a dictionary

```
videoIntroduction = json.loads(output['videoIntroduction'][0])
print(videoIntroduction[0]["content"])
print(videoIntroduction[0]["type"])
```

which prints

```
Everything in the world is a matrix
1
```

Comment: How do I get inside the videoIntroduction': ['[{"content": and get the "content" and and "type"? and then the userNickName is outside at the end :D :D I learn a lot from this. It's so nice :) and thank you!

Comment: Hi Andrew, sorry to disturb you. Maybe you can help me this last time? :) <3

Comment: Please show what  result you get from `output['videoIntroduction'][0]` before the json.loads

Comment: The output is _exact_ like you put it. [{"content":"Everything in the world is a matrix","type":1,"userId":""}]userNickName=Califax

Comment: @aquatic The issue as noted first by @facelessuser - see first paragraph of that answer.  Edit this answer to add a `replace` fix of the missing & before userName.

Answer (score 1):

The posted tag seemed to be a little malformed, so I had to fix it so it would parse, but with that said, I'll explain. Value seemed to open with `"` but then close with `'`. Also, it was assumed `userNickName=Califax` was missing a `&` before it. I could be wrong, but the basis of the answer should still be relevant.

In your example you find the input and assign it to `inputTag`. `inputTag` is an `input` element. When you use the form notation `input['key']`, it looks for an HTML attribute with name `key`. In your case you want to access `value`. The content of `value` is a very large string that has key, value pairs separated by `&`. BeautifulSoup has no knowledge of how the arbitrary data is stored, it simply returns the value of the desired attribute, which in your case is a very large string. We have have to parse that data as BeautifulSoup doesn't know how to.

In this case, we can simply remove the first `&` and then split the data by `&`. Then we can split each item returned by the first `=`. This will leave us with a structure of `[(key1, value1), (key2, value2), ...]`. This is perfect for creating a dictionary as that is format it needs. So we can call `dict` sending it our structure.

After that we have a dictionary whose keys equal each key in the HTML attribute `value`. We can simply access the key we want:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<input type="text" style="display: none" id="videoId" value='&videoId=139209&videoUrl=https://mp5.website.net/storage1/M03/10/92/aPODC10sfP-AcFDnAGhUgdKc7iA667.mp4&videoImg=https://mp5.website.net/storage1/M03/10/97/aPODCl0sfP-ACNFjAABmn9NL64Q064.png&videoIntroduction=[{"content":"Everything in the world is a matrix","type":1,"userId":""}]&userNickName=Califax'>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")

inputTag = soup.find("input", {"id": "videoId"})
output = inputTag["value"]
values = dict([x.split('=', 1) for x in output.lstrip('&').split('&')])

print('=== Values ===')
print(values)
print('=== Wanted videoUrl ===')
print(values['videoUrl'])
```

Output

```
=== Values ===                                                                                                                                                                        
{'videoId': '139209', 'videoUrl': 'https://mp5.website.net/storage1/M03/10/92/aPODC10sfP-AcFDnAGhUgdKc7iA667.mp4', 'videoImg': 'https://mp5.website.net/storage1/M03/10/97/aPODCl0sfP-ACNFjAABmn9NL64Q064.png', 'videoIntroduction': '[{"content":"Everything in the world is a matrix","type":1,"userId":""}]', 'userNickName': 'Califax'}                                 
=== Wanted videoUrl ===                                                                                                                                                               
https://mp5.website.net/storage1/M03/10/92/aPODC10sfP-AcFDnAGhUgdKc7iA667.mp4
```

Comment: Good explanation of what is happening!